# How to find a file by the content that it contains?

Tags: bash

I want to write a command which will find all files which contain given content. For example all files with phrase "iso file". I have written this command:

```
find -exec -grep -l "iso file"{}
```

But I get a message that there are no arguments for '-exec'. How this command should look like?

Comment: your syntax is slightly off.   `find . -exec grep -l "iso file" {} \;`   Notice that this will spawn a new grep for every file.  `grep -r "iso file" .` might be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-exec` action requires you to specify a semicolon-terminated command to execute.  You have omitted the semicolon.  You have also prepended a hyphen to the name of the `grep` command, with the result not likely to be the name of any command on your system.  Furthermore, if you proceed like this then you probably want to consider only regular files, not directories (or special files).  You could address all those concerns by writing the command like this:

```
find -type f -exec grep -l "iso file" {} \;
```

On the other hand, `find` is more of a hindrance than a help here, given that `grep` can perform a recursive search all on its own:

```
grep -lR "iso file" .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to print all the files/directories using xargs.

```
find ./ -type f -print | xargs grep -l "iso file"
```

In Case you want to print the whole line matched as well you can remove '-l' parameter from grep command and write something like this.

```
find ./ -type f -print | xargs grep "iso file"
```

Comment: This will fail if there are spaces or funky characters in the file names. Better to do something like `find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "iso file"` ... Those are zeroes.